# How do you add a superscript character into a Powerbuilder textbox?

Tags: textbox, powerbuilder, datawindow

Is there any way to do this in the Powerbuilder properties window for a datawindow's textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I stumbled across a simpler solution.  I copied and pasted a portion of the text from a pdf into the text property of a datawindow text contol.  The superscript character simply pasted in.  So I'm guessing that Dougman's solution would work too.

Example:
"™Trademark used under..."

Note: I'm using PB 9.0.1

Thanks for all the help,
Glenn

Answer (score 2):

That kind of depends on how you define "textbox", but in general the only way to mix normal and superscript text is with a richtext control. In PB 11.5, you can even use richtext as a column style.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  For the text control, you must select a font that has superscript characters (Arial does).

- Go into the Windows Character Map (usually in the start menu under Accessories->System Tools) and select your font.
- Then go to the superscript character that you want to place in your text control.  Click it and then click the Select button to place it down in the character map text box.
- Then click the Copy button.
- Now you can return to PowerBuilder and paste this value into the properties window text area.

As long as the same font is selected for the DataWindow control as was selected in the character map it should show as your superscript character.

This same techinque can be done to include any of the Wingding type characters as well.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using two separate text fields.  It's a butt-ugly solution, but it works.  The superscript field has a smaller font and is nudged a little higher up.

I think newer PB versions support superscripts.

Thanks for the help.

Glenn

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the character map - when you select your character it will show the keys to enter this character on the bottom right of the window.

Example : in Arial font - the `®` (registered) mark is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0174

To enter these, turn your numlock on, hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key down, and type <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>4</kbd> then let up on the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. You have to use the number keys on the number pad to do this the ones on the top of the keyboard dont work.

You can then enter your characters directly or do something like this :

`ls_key = '®`'